# Importing a dataset in R as double with tibble class

Tags: r, list, types, double, tidyverse

Excuse my lack of programming expertise, but this issue keeps appearing very often in my codes in R.

I upload a dataset with `read.csv` as:

```
db <- read.csv("data.csv", sep = ",")
typeof(db)
```

returns the database imported as a list.

Importing as:

```
db <- as.matrix(read.csv("data.csv", sep = ","))
typeof(db)
```

returns the dataset imported as double (the database contains homogeneous numeric data types).

Finally, the following:

```
db <- as.matrix(read.csv("data.csv", sep = ",")) %>% as_tibble()
typeof(db)
```

returns the dataset imported as list again. Hence, the conversion to a tibble converts the data type from double to list.

Since I oftern use tibbles and generally double data type is much more amenable to various applications, is there a way to import/convert the database as a matrix and at the same time as tibble class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an object of class matrix and tibble at the same time. To check the class of an object use `class(db)` instead of `typeof(db)`.

To import the data as tibble use `readr::read_csv` -

```
db <- readr::read_csv("data.csv")
class(db)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could read it with `base R` itself and wrap with `as_tibble`

```
db <- as_tibble(read.csv('data.csv'))
```